# Why MySQL Switch-Case is not selecting the right values?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the CASE statement in Mysql, and although MySQL doesn't complain about my query, it fails to deliver the right results.

What I'm attempting to do is the equivalent of:

```
if value < 20 then 1
elseif value < 30 then 2
elseif value < 40 then 3
.
.
.
else value < 90 then 45
```

and this is my MySQL statement:

```
SELECT
    UM.DA,
    UM.PA,
    IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) AS "PS",
CASE
    WHEN "PS" < 20 THEN 1
    WHEN "PS" < 30 THEN 2
    WHEN "PS" < 40 THEN 3
    WHEN "PS" < 50 THEN 5
    WHEN "PS" < 60 THEN 8
    WHEN "PS" < 70 THEN 12
    WHEN "PS" < 80 THEN 20
    WHEN "PS" < 90 THEN 30
    WHEN "PS" >= 90 THEN 45
END AS "Points",
FROM
    Table1 UM
```

and this is my result set:

```
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| UM.DA | UM.PA |   PS   | Points |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 19.21 | 18.39 |  18.39 |    1   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 24.80 | 34.91 |  34.91 |    1   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 29.72 | 35.89 |  35.89 |    1   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
```

This is how my result result should look like:

```
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| UM.DA | UM.PA |   PS   | Points |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 19.21 | 18.39 |  18.39 |    1   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 24.80 | 34.91 |  34.91 |    3   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 29.72 | 35.89 |  35.89 |    3   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+
```

So what is the right way to use "CASE" in MySQL Queries (this is a query, not a stored procedure)

Also, in terms of performance is it better to put this logic in the SQL query, or should I filter the results in the programming language of my choice?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you wrap PS in double-quotes in Case-When statement? It's a column name.

Comment: Because MySQL complains if I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DA, PA, PS,
       CASE
           WHEN PS < 20 THEN 1
           WHEN PS < 30 THEN 2
           WHEN PS < 40 THEN 3
           WHEN PS < 50 THEN 5
           WHEN PS < 60 THEN 8
           WHEN PS < 70 THEN 12
           WHEN PS < 80 THEN 20
           WHEN PS < 90 THEN 30
           ELSE 45
       END AS "Points"
FROM (SELECT DA, PA,
             IF((DA - PA) > 25, DA, PA) AS PS
      FROM Table1 UM) temp
```

It moves the `PS` calculation into a subquery, so it can be referenced in the `CASE` expression without repeating the calculation. And `PS` must be a name, not a string.

Comment: My version of MySQL complains if I don't remove the quotes, it returns "Unkown column PS in field list"

Comment: That's because you can't refer to an alias in the same SELECT list as it's defined. That's why I moved it into a subquery in my answer.

Comment: you should use backticks  here `UM.DA` or it will be considered as table and column

Comment: @echo_Me It *is* table and column.

Comment: One more question, how would the subquery work if I'm joining other tables in my query? I tried to write the subquery before selecting my first table, and after the LEFT JOINs and neither way has worked.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks a lot for your help, Your query works although for some reason is too slow for my dataset. I believe is because it's creating around 1000 derived tables, there are no indices and it's doing an ALL Join with them. In your opinion, would it better to move the switch case in another programming language?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting 1000 derived tables. There should be just one derived table for the subquery. If it's a complex join with other subqueries, you'll need those same derived tables either way. But if moving the code into the application language solves the problem, that's a fine way to do it, too.

Comment: I'm sorry I confused the derived tables with the number of rows. 
EXPLAIN EXTENDED shows that <derived2> it's examining 60902 rows although my initial selection only has 254.
I think I'll be better off moving the code into the application language. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the WHERE clause is in the subquery, not the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

`"PS"` is simply a string. It's NOT the alias you created, so you're comparing a string against an integer, and mysql will auto-convert that `"PS"` string to an int, making it 0, so ALL of the cases match. You want

```
CASE
    WHEN PS < 20 THEN 1
         ^^---note lack of quotes
```

Comment: You can't refer to aliases in the same select

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use an alias for a column inside a query, unless it's the ORDER BY clause.  As a result (particularly due to aliases by speech marks not backticks) you are doing a string comparison.  Change the query to:

```
SELECT
    UM.DA,
    UM.PA,
    IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) AS "PS",
CASE
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) < 20 THEN 1
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) < 30 THEN 2
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) < 40 THEN 3
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) < 50 THEN 5
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) < 60 THEN 8
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) < 70 THEN 12
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) < 80 THEN 20
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) < 90 THEN 30
    WHEN IF((UM.DA - UM.PA) > 25, UM.DA, UM.PA) >= 90 THEN 45
END AS "Points",
FROM
    Table1 UM
```